# Making async Task interface backwards compatible with monodroid

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a bunch of interfaces for a repository in a core class library that defines return types as Task.  These interfaces are used in other projects to define async methods.

I need to implement these same interfaces in a Xamarain monodroid project and was wondering how I should use the same return types without using async await since that's not supported yet in MonoDroid.  I don't want to modify the existing core library interfaces at all if possible.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `Microsoft.Bcl` it provides async and await for WP7 for instance. There is also a project called `AsyncBridge` which implements `Tasks` for PCLs, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you don't *have* to use `async`/`await`; it's just a lot easier than doing it "by hand". Your implementations just have to return `Task`s that are never `null` and already started (if applicable).

The [TAP document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) has some useful techniques and guidelines. One key type is `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` which you can use to wrap any asynchronous implementation (e.g., APM). Synchronous implementations can use `Task.FromResult` (which is just a small wrapper around `TaskCompletionSource`. If you have CPU work to do, you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, which is [closely related but not quite equivalent to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) `Task.Run`. For more complex implementations, you would need continuations a la `ContinueWith`.

In other words, all the .NET 4.0 TPL techniques can be used, as long as your returned `Task`s are always started. (The only way to get an unstarted `Task` is to construct it with the `Task` constructor and not call `Start`. So as long as you don't do this, you should be fine.)